# not re-rendering on setState

Tags: reactjs

I have a condition given below where I want to update an array of objects present in state, although the state is changing but not rendering, maybe somehow the state is being directly mutated, or any other reason. I'am unable to figure out what am I doing wrong

```
  handleCondition = e => {
    const { value, id } = e.target;
    this.setState(
      ({ newData }) => {
        const testData = newData;
        testData.find(data => data.variable === id.split('_')[1])[id.split('_')[0]] = value;
        return ({
          newData: testData
        });
      },
      () =>
        localStorage.setItem(
          "newData",
          JSON.stringify(this.state.newData)
        )
    );
  };
```

```
render(){
return(
 <select
    id={`wall_${data.variable}`}
    className="custom-slt-home"
    onChange={this.handleCondition}
    value={data.wall}
   >
    <option value="paint">Paint</option>
    <option value="wallpaper">Wallpaper</option>
 </select>
)
```

Comment: This isn't really enough to debug this. You can create runnable Javascript snippets here and you're more likely to get an answer if you use that to produce a working example.

Comment: I can guess you have shouldComponentUpdate on parent component which prevents update

Comment: Your array `testData` is still referencing the same array as `newData`, so when you say `testData.find(......) = value` you're setting state directly. You can solve this by creating a new array instead of referencing the same array. Change `const testData = newData` to `const testData = [...newData]`. This will create a new array, where you can then mutate its values, and use it to set the new state.

Comment: Also, `testData.find()` may return `undefined` so you should check that an object was found before accessing its properties with `[id.split('_')[0]]`

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
testData.find(data => data.variable === id.split('_')[1])[id.split('_')[0]] = value;
```

You don't mutate an array, so as a result you're returning to the `setState` the same value.

Try this instead:

```
const itemIndex = newData.findInex(data => data.variable === id.split('_')[1]);
const item = [...newData[itemIndex]];
item[id.split('_')[0] = value;
return ({
   newData: [...newData.slice(0, itemIndex), item, ...newData.slice(itemIndex + 1)];
});
```

There may be some issues, because you didn't provide any info about your data structure. But I hope you'll understand the point.